# AsyncStream not executing closure

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, asyncstream

so I'm reading the Modern Concurrency book from raywenderlich.com and I assume the book must be outdated or something, I'm trying to run the `closure` insde the `AsyncStream` but it doesn't seem to get there, I'm still pretty new to this Async/Await thing, but when adding some breakpoints I can see my code is not getting there. This is my code and a screenshot with some warnings showing. I am not really familiar with what the warnings mean, just trying to learn all this new stuff, I would truly appreciate some help and is there a way to fix it with Swift 6? Thanks in advance!

> Reference to captured var 'countdown' in concurrently-executing code; this is an error in Swift 6

> Mutation of captured var 'countdown' in concurrently-executing code; this is an error in Swift 6

```
func countdown(to message: String) async throws {
    guard !message.isEmpty else { return }
    var countdown = 3

    let counter = AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
      Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
          continuation.yield("\(countdown)...")
          countdown -= 1
        }
    }

    for await countDownMessage in counter {
      try await say(countDownMessage)
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: A new version of the book will be available shortly, this is one of the issues that has been addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Timer.scheduleTimer` requires that it be scheduled on a run loop. In practical terms, that means we would want to schedule it on the main thread’s run loop. So, you either call `scheduleTimer` from the main thread, or create a `Timer` and manually [`add(_:forMode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418468-add) it to [`RunLoop.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418388-main) . See the *Scheduling Timers in Run Loops* section of the `Timer` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer).

The easiest way would be to just isolate this function to the main actor. E.g.,

```swift
@MainActor
func countdown(to message: String) async throws { … }
```

There a few other issues here, too:

1. I would suggest defining the `countdown` variable within the `AsyncStream`:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func countdown(to message: String) async throws {
       guard !message.isEmpty else { return }

       let counter = AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
           var countdown = 3
           Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
               continuation.yield("\(countdown)...")
               countdown -= 1
           }
       }

       for await countDownMessage in counter {
           try await say(countDownMessage)
       }
   }
   ```
2. The `AsyncStream` is never finished. You might want to finish it when it hits zero:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func countdown(to message: String) async throws {
       guard !message.isEmpty else { return }

       let counter = AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
           var countdown = 3
           Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
               continuation.yield("\(countdown)...")

               // presumably you want this countdown timer to finish when it hits zero

               guard countdown > 0 else {
                   timer.invalidate()
                   continuation.finish()
                   return
               }

               // otherwise, decrement and carry on

               countdown -= 1
           }
       }

       for await countDownMessage in counter {
           try await say(countDownMessage)
       }
   }
   ```
3. There should be a `continuation.onTermination` closure to handle cancelation of the asynchronous sequence.

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func countdown(to message: String) async throws {
       guard !message.isEmpty else { return }

       let counter = AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
           var countdown = 3
           let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
               continuation.yield("\(countdown)...")

               // presumably you want this countdown timer to finish when it hits zero

               guard countdown > 0 else {
                   timer.invalidate()
                   continuation.finish()
                   return
               }

               // otherwise, decrement and carry on

               countdown -= 1
           }

           continuation.onTermination = { _ in
               timer.invalidate()
           }
       }

       for await countDownMessage in counter {
           try await say(countDownMessage)
       }
   }
   ```

Going back to the original question (why this is not running), I personally would avoid the use of `Timer` in conjunction with Swift concurrency at all. A GCD timer would be better, as it doesn’t require a `RunLoop`. Even better, I would advise `Task.sleep`. Needless to say, that is designed to work with Swift concurrency, and also is cancelable.

I personally would suggest something like:

```swift
func countdown(to message: String) async throws {
    guard !message.isEmpty else { return }
    
    let counter = AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
        let task = Task {
            for countdown in (0...3).reversed() {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                continuation.yield("\(countdown)...")
            }
            
            continuation.finish()
        }
        
        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    for await countDownMessage in counter {
        try await say(countDownMessage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Task.sleep is the method used in the updated version of the book

Comment: Oh boy! Thanks a lot, your answer was really helpful, you gave me all the context needed to actually understand what's happening and how to solve it. Thanks a lot!!